# Warum steht das Verb an erster Stelle?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Später, als Gold-, Silber- und Kupfertaler aufkamen, ordnete man auch Bleimünzen dieser Kategorie »Alternativgeld« zu. Im Vergleich zur Goldmünze besaßen die Bleitaler einen geringeren Edelmetallanteil. Deswegen verwahrte man dieses »schlechte Geld« nicht im Säckel, unterm Kopfkissen oder in der Geldschatulle, sondern gab es schnell wieder aus. **Brachte** es für Wein, Brot, Heringe oder ein Obdach unters Volk **, zurück** in den lokalen Wirtschaftskreislauf

2. Warum steht "zurück" nicht am Ende
3. Warum wird ein Komma hier geschrieben?

Comment: Nochmal: in der deutsche Sprache ist die Wortreihenfolge sehr frei und transportiert eine Bedeutung: dem Schreiber war die Betonung von „zurück“ (im übrigen ist das kein Verb) wichtig, weshalb er es an den Anfang stellt. Wäre ihn der lokale Wirtschaftswandel wichtiger, hätte er es anders formuliert. Unvollständige Nebensätze (hier fehlt das Verb) werden in Deutsch mit Komma abgetrennt.

Comment: Was war Punkt 1. nochmal bitte?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Der erste Punkt ist die Frage, warum das Verb brachte an erster Stelle steht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der vollständige Satz lautet

> **Man** brachte es für Wein, Brot, Heringe oder ein Obdach unters Volk, zurück in den lokalen Wirtschaftskreislauf.

Das **man** wurde in deinem Beispiel ausgelassen, um es nicht zu wiederholen. Das Stilmittel heißt *Ellipse*.

---

Nach Bearbeitung der Frage:

Es handelt sich auch beim letzten Satz wieder um eine Ellipse.

> **(Sondern) man brachte es** zurück in den lokalen Wirtschaftskreislauf.

Das Komma wurde gesetzt, um diese beiden Hauptsätze als gedanklich zusammenhängend zu verketten. Dieser Stil, in mit vielen Ellipsen verketteten Hauptsätzen zu schreiben, kommt mir sehr lateinisch vor, ist aber auch im Deutschen üblich.

Mein letzter Satz ist wiederum ein Beispiel für diesen Stil. Es ist ein *er* am Anfang des letzten Hauptsatzes ausgelassen, und statt des Punktes steht ein Komma.

Comment: Ich sehe das anders. Ich denke, dass das *sondern* immer noch nachwirkt und logisch ein Komma an Stelle eines Punktes zwischen die Sätze gehört, was aber nicht dem intendierten Rhythmus entsprochen hätte.

Comment: Da würde aber immer noch ein *man* fehlen.

Answer (score 0):

Dass das Verb **brachte** an erster Stelle steht, ist schlicht falsche Grammatik. Statt eines Punktes müsste hier ein Komma stehen. Dann wäre es einfach ein Stilmittel wie von Janka beschrieben. Durch den Punkt enthält der letzte Satz kein Subjekt. Das geht eigentlich nicht.

In künstlerischen Texten ist es durchaus möglich, bewusst gegen die Grammatik zu verstoßen. Inwieweit dieser Text Kunst ist, weiß ich nicht.

Den letzten Teil

> , zurück in den lokalen Wirtschaftskreislauf

kann man so verstehen, wie Janka es beschreibt. Man kann aber

> [b]rachte es ... unters Volk , zurück in den lokalen Wirtschaftskreislauf

auch einfach als Aufzählung sehen. In beiden Fällen ist ein Komma notwendig.

*zurück in den lokalen Wirtschaftskreislauf* und *in den lokalen Wirtschaftskreislauf zurück* sind gleichwertig.

Wenn man will, kann man in den unterschiedlichen Stellungen des Wortes *zurück* unterschiedliche Bedeutungsschwerpunkte sehen.

- so schnell wie möglich *zurück* (in den Wirtschaftskreislauf) [weil es nichts wert ist] könnte hier durch die Stellung als hervorgehobene Bedeutung betrachtet werden
- *in den lokalen Wirtschaftskreislauf* (zurück) wäre in anderen Kontexten denkbar als Reihenfolge, die die Wichtigkeit des Geldflusses hervorheben soll